# Django: How to compare two different data table for datafield and get match exactly correct data?

Tags: python, django, django-models

### Models.py

```
class Newspaper (models.Model):
        newspaper = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        language = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Language)
        wh_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
        sa_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        publication = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Publication)

class Daily_Cart(models.Model):
        ac_no       = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        newspaper = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        added_date  = models.DateTimeField(max_length=32,auto_now_add=True)
```

---

### daily_update.py

```
def bill():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().day
    if current_time == 27:
        news = Newspaper.objects.all()

        daily = Daily_Cart.objects.all()
        for x in news:
            if x.publication=='Weekdays':
                for xc in daily:
                    print(xc.newspaper, x)
```

Daily_cart table have to compere with newspaper table. If data exits have to print newspaper AND ac_no. This result i expect to.

### Here you can see models /Newspaper/Daily_cart
*[image: Here you can see models /Newspaper/Daily_cart]*

### print(xc.newspaper, x)

```
monnews  monnews
```

---

### if use print(set(xc.newspaper)& set(x)) i got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Project--Django\Pro_Venv\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Project--Django\Pro_Venv\NewspaperAPI\invoice.py", line 18, in bill
    print(set(xc.newspaper)& set(x))
TypeError: 'Newspaper' object is not iterable
```

Comment: isnt it better to use ForeignKey ?

Comment: i already have many to many with newspaper model.  i try to did but not work ? Consumer_order.objects.filter(newspaper__Newspaper_publication=['Weekdays']) ; trace back:- django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column NewspaperAPI_daily_cart.newspaper_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ly_cart"."id", "NewspaperAPI_daily_cart"."ac_no", "Newspaper...

Comment: for eb in Consumer_order.objects.filter(newspaper__publication='Weekdays'):
            for ebc in eb.newspaper.all():

Comment: filter not show many to many field data?

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
print(xc.newspaper, x)
```

Should be

```
print(str(xc.newspaper), str(x.newspaper))
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'Newspaper'

Comment: I edited my answer and convert the values to a string.

Comment: No you got wrong. i know string covertion. in case customer_order have to cross check with newspaper publications then if any paper have for weekday then show paper and customer Ac_no also. this actually i am look for if you know. let me teach how to do it.